# Linear algebra- Find inverse for block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a 3*3 matrix of the form
$\begin{bmatrix}
    a       & 0  \\
    0       & D \\
\end{bmatrix}$, 
where a is a constant and D is a 2*2 matrix. How can I find the inverse of the matrix ?

Also, for a more general case with
$\begin{bmatrix}
    A       & 0  \\
    0       & D \\
\end{bmatrix}$,  A and D both matrices. How can I express the inverse?

Thnaks!

Answer (score 3):

For the inverse matrix, replace $a$ by $\frac{1}{a}$ and the matrix $D$ by its inverse

In the general case you also replace the matrix $A$ by its inverse